PBS job terminates prematurely, resulting in partial execution of its underlying scripts when it encounters an orphaned Docker container
I have an application running every 5 minutes which utilizes Docker and PBS for its execution.
The application is a python script which is executed via PBS script in a docker container.
This is the PBS script which uses rm_test docker image for execution
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=8:mem=40G,walltime=00:10:00
#PBS -N regmod_realtime_forecast
#PBS -o output_regmod_realtime_forecast.log
#PBS -e error_regmod_realtime_forecast.log
#PBS -q Hercules
#PBS -v CONTAINER_IMAGE=rm_test_202402
#PBS -p 100
#MANDATORY
source ~/.bashrc
####


#su - seradmin
cd /data/regional_model/src
python _realtime_forecast.py

validation_result=$(python ~/scripts/regmod_forecast_validation.py)

if [ "$validation_result" == "False" ]; then
        python _realtime_forecast.py
fi

The architecture works fine most of the time but, Once in a blue-moon, the PBS comes across an orphan container. In this situation, The pbs terminates prematurely by partially executing the underlying python script.
[PBS logs of an irregular executionstrong text]
**05/01/2024 12:30:26;0080;pbs_python;Hook;pbs_python;Cleaning up orphaned container: "373189.oracle"**
05/01/2024 12:30:27;0100;pbs_python;Hook;PBS_hpc_container;argv new: /opt/pbs/sbin/pbs_container 373189.oracle 0 /opt/pbs exec -w /home/seradmin 373189.oracle /bin/bash -c /var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/373189.oracle.SC
05/01/2024 12:30:27;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;Started, pid = 259270
05/01/2024 12:30:28;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;pid 260117 sid 260117 cmd 373189.orac attached as task 00000002
05/01/2024 12:30:28;0001;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;tm_attach: sid 260117 already attached
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;no active process for task 00000002
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;no active process for task 00000002
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0080;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;task 00000001 terminated
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;Terminated
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0100;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;task 00000001 cput=00:00:00
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0100;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;task 00000002 cput=00:00:05
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;kill_job
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0100;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;oracle cput=00:00:05 mem=229672kb
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0100;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;Obit sent
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0080;pbs_python;Hook;pbs_python;373189.oracle cleaned up successfully
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0080;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;copy file request received
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0100;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;Staged 2/2 items out over 0:00:00
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0080;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;delete job request received
05/01/2024 12:30:37;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 12:30:38;0008;pbs_mom;Job;373189.oracle;kill_job"

[PBS logs of a healthy execution]
05/01/2024 22:55:27;0100;pbs_python;Hook;PBS_hpc_container;argv new: /opt/pbs/sbin/pbs_container 374116.oracle 0 /opt/pbs exec -w /home/seradmin 374116.oracle /bin/bash -c /var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/374116.oracle.SC
05/01/2024 22:55:27;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;Started, pid = 232270
05/01/2024 22:55:28;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;pid 233081 sid 233081 cmd 374116.orac attached as task 00000002
05/01/2024 22:55:28;0001;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;tm_attach: sid 233081 already attached
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;no active process for task 00000002
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0080;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;task 00000001 terminated
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;Terminated
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0100;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;task 00000001 cput=00:00:01
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0100;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;task 00000002 cput=00:01:50
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;kill_job
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0100;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;oracle cput=00:01:51 mem=3779196kb
05/01/2024 22:56:31;0100;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;Obit sent
05/01/2024 22:56:32;0080;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;copy file request received
05/01/2024 22:56:32;0100;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;Staged 2/2 items out over 0:00:00
05/01/2024 22:56:32;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 22:56:32;0080;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;delete job request received
05/01/2024 22:56:41;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 22:56:42;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 22:56:42;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;no active tasks
05/01/2024 22:56:43;0008;pbs_mom;Job;374116.oracle;kill_job

It is observed that whenever PBS comes across an orphaned container, the job exits prematurely.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Can you [edit] the question to include the script and outputs in plain text?  For a [mcve], is there any details beyond just this script a reader needs to understand?
